# i m trying to make an app which can load website given in EditText field.like web browser.but ii am getting error at Url.parse method

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    String str;
    EditText username;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.uname);
        str = username.getText().toString();
    }

    public void goClick(View v){
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(str)); //here instead of str if i use specific website it will work    but for str it wll not work
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
}
```

If i put http://www.google.co.uk/ in place of `str` in the `Uri.parse()`, the function works.

Example:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.google.co.uk"));
```

If i try to set `str = 'http://www.google.co.uk'`, it doesn't work.

Any idea as to why?

Comment: __specific websit it wll work    but for str it wll not work__ can you explain it little more??

Answer (score 1):

You just move

`str = username.getText().toString();`

in `goClick(.....)`

### Like

```
public void goClick(View v){

str = username.getText().toString()

Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",Uri.parse(str));

startActivity(browserIntent);

}
```